# Load ArcGIS digitized image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gis, arcgis

I am New to GIS platform.

In my project (A windows application) I'm trying to load an image in PictureBox(A drone image of an area) is in GeoTIFF format about 950+ MB's. This image digitized(mark boundries of every house and labelled with house no) and data imported in Shapefile. I extracted XY coordinate data using following code. I reduced the original image size to about 40-45 MB's and converted in JPG format.

Now I have to plot that XY coordinate data in my windows application on the new reduced image.

How should I achieve this scenario?
What exactly should I do?
I am not able to load the Original image about 950+ MB's?

*Code For getting XY coordinates from Shapefile*

```
private void ReadShapeFile(string path)
{
    ShapeFile.MapFilesInMemory = true;
    // open the shapefile
    EGIS.ShapeFileLib.ShapeFile sf = new EGIS.ShapeFileLib.ShapeFile(path);
    try
    {
        sf.RenderSettings = new EGIS.ShapeFileLib.RenderSettings(path, "", this.Font);
        EGIS.ShapeFileLib.DbfReader dbfr = sf.RenderSettings.DbfReader;
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("output.txt"))
        {
            EGIS.ShapeFileLib.ShapeFileEnumerator sfEnum = sf.GetShapeFileEnumerator();
            int recordIndex = 0;
            while (sfEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                string rec = "";
                string NoOfCord = "";
                string coord = "";
                rec = string.Format("Record:{0}", recordIndex);
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Record:{0}", recordIndex));
                System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<PointD[]> pointRecords = sfEnum.Current;
                foreach (PointD[] pts in pointRecords)
                {
                    writer.Write(string.Format("[NumPoints:{0}]", pts.Length));
                    NoOfCord = string.Format("[NumPoints:{0}]", pts.Length);
                    for (int n = 0; n < pts.Length; ++n)
                    {
                        if (n > 0) writer.Write(',');
                        writer.Write(pts[n].ToString());
                        if (n > 0) coord += ",";
                        coord += pts[n].ToString();
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }
                AddDataToDataTable(recordIndex, rec, NoOfCord, coord);
                ++recordIndex;
            }
            sfEnum.Dispose();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Data Loaded Successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("Error Message - " + enl + ex.Message + enl + "Error StackTrace - " + enl + ex.StackTrace + enl); }
    finally
    {
        sf.Close();
        sf.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I´m not sure I understood every point of your question. Doesn´t the JPEG already contain the xy-coords of the houses? So you can just show that within your winforms-app. Why need the original GeoTIFF at all?

Comment: the image digitized in arcGIS..so in digitizing process house points(i.e. polygon) are plotted..therefore xy-coords doesn't contain in JPEG file itself..@HimBromBeere

Comment: So what *does* the JPEG contain? Anyway, an **image** is just a raster (containing colums and rows), whereas *digitizing* is something you do with **vector**-data. So **digitizing** an **JPEG** don´t fit together, however Shapefile and digitizing do, as a shapefile is a *vector*-format. So please be clear on if you´re working on raster- or vector-data. Winforms however can´t show a shape-file, it can however show an image (=raster-data).

Comment: I digitize data using ArcGIS on GeoTIFF img..And I created shpfile of this..That's the only work with ArcGIS application..Now I want show the img in winforms and also  I want to show my marking on winforms..for that purpose I converted img to JPEG so that I can load it on my winforms..And using shpfile I extracted xy-cooords..Using that coordinates I am trying to plot polygon on the image in my .net application(i.e. in winforms)..Now the problem is the xy-coords are going outside of the image..in this case what will be useful for me?

Comment: So in fact you want to show a compressed version of your GeoTIFF and the house-polygons within your winforms-app?

Comment: Yeah....Exaclty....I found one code which load [shpfile data](http://easygisdotnet.com/api/Example1.aspx) ...Now all I need either this data should have img in background or relative map...

Comment: But can´t you simply export your whole map to JPG within ArcMap or Arcgis Pro? This way you keep the coordinate-system. Or do you really need two image-files, one for the background and one containing the polygons?

Comment: What I have to do is, I have to customize polygon colour according to request/filter...I have other details in my database like no. of family members, ages,etc. and suppose I have to highlight those house having family members more than 5...at that time what I want to do is, I will change color for those houses...for that I need coords for each house....This all I want to do in my .Net application

Answer (score 0):

**First**: loading huge image needs pyramid or tile cutting; if you want your application to show the full image, please cut tile or build pyramid and then show it in **mapcontrol** which in the **dotspatial** or **sharpmap** libraries.

**Second**: if you have not cropped your images, the proccessed image would have the same **real extent** with original image. You can caculate the **real position** of any pixel in the image; you can also transform the real position (lat/lon or projection coordinate) to the **image coordinate reference** (which top-left is (0,0)).